# Does in this case exist necessarely an eigenvalue equal to $0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, coordinate-systems, several-complex-variables

I pasted more than I refer, hoping to be more clear.

Look at the claim of the theorem: it states we can change coordinates untill we reach a "good" form for the equation of $r$, which defines the hypersurface $M$.

So let's consider the equation
$$
r=y_1+\sum_{j=2}^{s^++1}|z_j|^2-\sum_{j=s^++2}^{s^++s^-+1}|z_j|^2 + o^2(x_1,z')
$$
if we take the Levi form of $r$ around $0$, looking at the previous equation, we MUST have an eigenvalue equal to $0$.
Do you agree? It seems a little bit strange: we are saying that the Levi form of every $r:\Bbb C^n\to\Bbb R$ twice differentiable has at least one eigenvalue equal to zero. Taking $r=|z_1|^2+\cdots+|z_n|^2$ we'd have all the eigenvalues equal to $1$. No eigenvalue vanishes.

Where is the problem?

[image]

Comment: The Levi form is defined as the complex Hessian of a defining function restricted to the complex tangent hyperplane, i.e. to a space of dim $n-1$. So, if you start with a (Levi)convex hypersurface and you write it locally as $y_1=Q+hot$ around the origin, the Levi form in the origin will be restricted to the hyperplane $z_1=0$ (the vanishing direction you were complaining about)

Comment: @wisefool: many thanks. Write your comment (just paste it) as an answer;  I'd be happy to put your answer as good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Levi form is defined as
$$L_M(z)=L_r(z)\vert_{T^{\mathbb{C}}_zM}$$
i.e. as the complex hessian of $r$ restricted to the maximal complex subspace of the tangent to $M$.

If you put $M$ in the form
$$y_1=Q(z_2,\ldots, z_n)+h.o.t.$$
locally around $0$, then the tangent hyperplane in $0$ is $y_1=0$, so the complex tangent is $z_1=0$, i.e.
$$T^{\mathbb{C}}_0M=\mathrm{Span}\{\partial_{z_2}, \ldots, \partial_{z_n}\}\;.$$
If you denote by $A$ the matrix associated with the quadratic form $Q$, then
$$L_r(0)=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&\cdots& 0\\0& &  &\\\vdots& &A& \\0& & & \end{pmatrix}$$
with respect to the basis $\{\partial_{z_1},\ldots, \partial_{z_n}\}$ of $T_0\mathbb{C}^n$. Now, if you restrict this to $T^{\mathbb{C}}_0M$, you obtain the $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ matrix $A$, which is $L_M(0)$.

If $Q$ was positive definite, then so it is $L_M(0)$. The direction of the $0$ eigenvector is precisely the one you get rid of when restricting to the maximal complex subspace of $T_0M$.